# Meteor on collection change update Template select element

Tags: meteor

I am using [`bootstrap-select`](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) to help make select elements look better in my Meteor app.

However, I am running into an issue where upon submitting changes to the Meteor Collection, the reactivity pushes out changes back to the templates, thus rewriting the select elements and destroy the original select element, which also take away the `bootstrap-select` stuff.

I wonder if there's a way for me to prevent this from happening somehow. 
I tried to listen to the changes and recall `selectpicker` upon an update but it doesn't work.

```
Applications.find().observe({
changed: function() {
    console.log('something changed');
            $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
}
});
```

I even try to delay things a little bit, also to no avail.

```
Applications.find().observe({
changed: function() {
    console.log('something changed');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
        console.log('trying to update select picker');
    }, 1000);
}
});
```

Has anyone run into this problem before and know how to fix it?

EDIT: Here's the template code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="college" class="control-label">College/ University</label>
    <select class="selectpicker" name="college" placeholder="Select a College/ University">
        {{#each colleges}}
            <option value="{{slug}}">{{name}}</option>
        {{/each}}
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML-template, if you surround your select-element with [the constant block helper](http://docs.meteor.com/#constant), the part inside the constant block won't be re-rendered. Maybe that would be a solution?

Comment: That's a good idea. But if it's in a constant block, would that means it will not get any update on model changes? Would a preserve block work?

Comment: @Tri - It is as you're saying: updates to documents in the constant block helper won't be showed. The best place to put `$('.selectpicker').selectpicker()` is probably in the function `Template.yourTemplateName.rendered`, but then the selected element in your bootstrap-select element will be created from scratch on every re rendering, and the previous selected item won't be selected any more. I can't think of an easy way to solve this, but if I were you, I would go with this solution and additionally add `selected="selected"` to the selected `<option>` in your select.

Comment: Thanks @Peppe, I am already calling it in the `rendered` function, but that doesn't solve the issue mentioned in my question, which is that on model changes, the `select` element is refreshed, thus booting out `bootstrap-select`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Turns out that removing 'preserve-inputs' package from my Meteor app helped. Maybe it's worth trying? Or if you don't want to do that, taking id and/or name attributes away from your select element seems to have same impact.

Comment: I don't think taking `id` or `name` away is a good idea - they're there for a reason, both semantic and allows form processing after.

Comment: No, I wouldn't do that either. Personally, I'm yet to find a reasonably working select replacement for Meteor app.

Answer (score 1):

Things changed a bit since this question was asked. With the new Blaze rendering engine the rendered event would only be thrown once. At the time of rendering, the options are not available, resulting in a nice styled but empty select.

The following example takes care of these changes. The trick is to render the selectpicker once on startup and then refresh whenever there's a change to an option. Therefore the `<option>` has to be moved to it's own template block.

Template:

```
<template name="whatever">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="college" class="control-label">College/ University</label>
    <select class="selectpicker" name="college" placeholder="Select a College/ University">
        {{#each colleges}}
            {{> selectOption}}
        {{/each}}
  </select>
</div>
</template>

<template name="selectOption">
    <option value="{{slug}}">{{name}}</option>
</template>
```

JavaScript:

```
Template.whatever.rendered = function(){
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
};

var renderTimeout = false;
Template.selectOption.rendered = function(){
  if(renderTimeout !== false) {
    Meteor.clearTimeout(renderTimeout);
  }
  renderTimeout = Meteor.setTimeout(function() {
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker("refresh");
    renderTimeout = false;
  }, 10)
};
```

Refreshing is a bit tricky. When you're loading your collection into the select, the event would be thrown for each option. In my case I have hundreds of documents/options. This results in refreshing hundreds of times and the browser hangs for a few seconds. Therefore there is this small timeout, which takes care of refreshing only once for a bulk of changes.